# OAuth2 without Auth Token for Third Party Applications

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to integrate Foundry with the central API gateway of our organisation.

Access of the gateway should be granted via OAuth2 via the "Third Party Applications" functionality of Foundry.

Now I am facing the problem, that our API Gateway only supports the Client Credential Flow in which no Authorization Token is used but only the Access Token. Is there a possibility to make Foundry follow the simplified flow w/o Auth token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundry supports the OAuth2 Authorization Code grant which provides delegated access to Foundry resources and services.

Support for the OAuth2 Client Credentials grant, which allows service user access, is under limited release with a few customers. If it’s not available for you please reach out through your internal support channels. A general release is expected early this spring, I'll try and update here if that timeframe slips.

Comment: Hi Tom, are you affiliated with Palantir or Palantir's Foundry product? It sounds like you might be based on the wording of your answer.

Comment: Seems like this feature has been rolled out to our stack recently.